# Read only filesystem problem

Tags: permissions, filesystem

I created a folder and I did:

```
chmod 777 anotherFolder/
```

I ran:

```
sudo mount -o loop folder/isoImage.iso anotherFolder/
```

The permissions of `anotherFolder/` changed to "Read Only" and I can not `chmod` it back to `777`, even with `sudo`. How can I `chmod` it to `777` ? It outputs me: `Read Only File System`.

I checked during 2 days in several forums but in vain :(

Comment: Yes, I saw similar questions to mine, including the one on your link with the solutions they provided but no one of them worked for me, unfortunately. Regards

Comment: And I am not mounting a USB key, just an already existing folder with an ISO image file

Comment: @Ploutox ISO file cannot be mount with write access

Comment: @c0rp good point. My bad ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO file is special file format called `ISO 9660`. Here is quote from wikipedia

> Since ISO 9660 is by design a read-only, pre-mastered file system, all
>   the data has to be written in one go or "session" to the medium.

So as a file system is read-only, you cannot mount it with write access.

But you can recreate ISO file, if you want.

1. You should mount your *.iso file somewhere
2. Then copy it to some temp folder
3. Using `mkisofs` util create new ISO file.

Here is a little example:

```
sudo mount -o loop folder/isoImage.iso anotherFolder/
mkdir new_copy_of_iso
cp -R anotherFolder/* new_copy_of_iso/
umount anotherFolder
mkisofs -R -o name_new.iso new_copy_of_iso
```

Comment: Thank you very much c0rp. You have the same idea as Benoit, but I need mkisofs

Answer (score 1):

Mounting an ISO file (a CD-ROM image) read-write is not possible. By nature, this is a read-only filesystem that has to be written in one go.

To alter the content of the ISO file, once mounted like you've done, you can copy the content to another directory, make your changes there and recreate the ISO file from there too.
You can use the command `mkisofs` to create an ISO file from any directory structure or you can use the graphical tool integrated into Ubuntu (right-click on the CD-ROM icon appearing on your desktop when you insert a (blank) CD-ROM).

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea, Benoit. I am going to test it right now. As you guessed it, I want to modify the "extracted" ISO image files and folders. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @begueradj: If Benoit's answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: I do not know how to make it "answered" question. I am new to here. Sorry, but I will check how to do it