# How to format readonly file system - USB

Tags: usb, filesystem, format

I'm trying to format a USB that is readonly. I've mistakenly removed the SecureAccess files and now the file system is readonly. 
I've tried some solutions like this:

[Read only filesystem problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441845/read-only-filesystem-problem)

But still no result. 
In proc/mounts file /dev/sdb is of type iso9660 ro.

Is there another solution I should try? Thanks.

Edited: After trying to format from disks I got the following error:

```
Error formatting disk
Error wiping device: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/sdb"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:
stdout: `5 bytes were erased at offset 0x8001 (iso9660)
they were: 43 44 30 30 31
'
stderr: `wipefs: error: /dev/sdb: probing initialization failed
' (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Comment: Follow the steps in this post ->https://askubuntu.com/questions/747702/sd-card-formating-process-failled-as-had-been-mistakly-unplugged/747730#747730

Comment: How did you tried to format? Do you tried to create a partition on the USB drive?

Comment: I edited my question and added the output from the format.

Answer (score 2):

- I think it works to restore the USB drive to a standard storage device with mkusb

  If you run standard Ubuntu, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
  ```

  See these links for more details,

  - [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/)
  - [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)
- If there are still problems, I suggest that you try according to this link:

  - [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried ... Analysis of the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
To format it:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd*
```

in my case it was:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

It took some time. After that I format the USB using Disks.

Applied permissions:

`sudo chmod 666 /dev/sd*`

Mounted it using:

```
 sudo mount -o rw,users,umask=000  /dev/sd* /media/user/temp
```

Comment: This is what I got: sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda1
dd: failed to open '/dev/sda1': Read-only file system

Comment: @raphael75 same :(